# LabVIEW: How to update a variable outside event structure in a while loop

Tags: events, labview

I have an event driven code inside a while loop and I would like to increment Numeric on its own and when the user selects a button then the event needs to be executed.

But with this implementation I can only update Numeric once per clicking OK button. I want to keep Numeric updating on its own.

[image]
[image]

Could anyone please shed some light ?

Thanks,

Comment: How fast do you want numeric to update?

Answer (score 0):

The [LabVIEW help](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361P-01/glang/event_structure/) for the Event Structure says:

> Waits until an event occurs, then executes the appropriate case to
>   handle that event.

So the second frame of the outer sequence structure is not going to complete until the event structure exits, and that's not going to happen until an event occurs.

The immediate solution to what I think you want is to wire a constant to the **Timeout** terminal of the event structure:

> This structure can time out while waiting for notification of an
>   event. Wire a value to the Timeout terminal at the top left of the
>   Event structure to specify the number of milliseconds the Event
>   structure waits for an event. The default is -1, which indicates never
>   to time out.

Now the event structure will exit after the specified time, if the button wasn't clicked.

This probably isn't the most elegant way of implementing what you actually want to do, though. As a rule of thumb if your LabVIEW diagram is full of sequence structures you are probably not using LabVIEW the way it's designed, i.e. with dataflow and events controlling program flow. If you can edit your question to explain how you actually want your program to behave, we may be able to suggest better ways of structuring it.